# Executing jar issue - uncaught error fetching image

Tags: java, image, executable-jar

I've made an audio player and the jar was made with netbeans. To load the images I've used:

```
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    URL playerIconURL = cl.getResource("tp/audioplayer/Images/icon.png");
    if (playerIconURL != null){

        ImageIcon playerIcon = new ImageIcon(playerIconURL);
        frame.setIconImage(playerIcon.getImage());
    }
    else{

        System.err.println("cannot load player icon");
    }
```

I mention that the folder Images is in the src/tp/audioplayer.

When I'm running the application inside netbeans everything is allright, but when I execute the jar in command prompt,the application starts but it's blank and it blocks and I get:

[image]

Can you tell me what I've done wrong or what is the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of these:

```
// using getResourceAsStream
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "picture.gif" );
// or
InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream( "stuff.ser" );
// or
InputStream is = MyApp.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( "InWords.properties" );
```

The resource in the jar file must be qualified with same package name as the class you call getResourceAsStream from. Alternatively, you can use an absolute name beginning with a / where dots get mapped to /s. If you don’t have a lead /, you have a relative name, and the name of the package will be prepended. If you use a /, you must include the name of the package yourself, or whatever name the resource is filed under in the jar.
For example you could specify /com/mindprod/mypackage/mystuff.ser or /com.mindprod.mypackage.mystuff.ser or simply mystuff.ser. Don’t use Windows style filenames with . These are not filenames, but Java resources that live along with the class files either in jars or sometimes freestanding on disk, or on the server.

In theory, getResourceAsStream will look in the local classpath, in the jar and in the directory where the class file was loaded from.

Comment: I've tried as you said and I still get that error. Maybe I didn't put my folder properly into the project folder?                           This is the full path D:\College\Individual Projects\Java\Audio Player\src\tp\audioplayer\ld . In ld are the last folders with the classes and now I've moved the Images folder in ld; When I posted the Images folder was in audioplayer.

Comment: I solved my issue and it was better with InputStream, so thx :)

Answer (score 1):

If tp is in your classpath you will have to load it with `cl.getResource("/tp/audioplayer/Images/icon.png")` if tp is NOT a source folder (but still added to the buildpath.

If you add tp as a sourcefolder then 
`cl.getResource("/audioplayer/Images/icon.png")`

Note that jars are casesensitive, make sure you the case-sensitive file-path.

Comment: all my packages are like tp.audioplayer.ld. and so on, and if I let cl.getResource("/audioplayer/Images/icon.png"), like you say it won't load the image at all.

Comment: See edit, forgot to add the first path. Assumed tp was a source folder (usually you add resources root folder as a source folder to avoid having to add one more directory to the path).

Comment: Still cannot add the image at all if I start the path with / . I get the error message which is from else statement

Comment: As I said to @Juned, the full path is D:\College\Individual Projects\Java\Audio Player\src\tp\audioplayer\ld . In ld are the last folders with the classes and now I've moved the Images folder in ld; When I posted the Images folder was in audioplayer.